# MySQL group by with MAX not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ID | User | Amount
1  | 1    | 50
2  | 1    | 80
3  | 2    | 80
4  | 2    | 100
5  | 1    | 90
6  | 1    | 120
7  | 2    | 120
8  | 1    | 150
9  | 2    | 300
```

I do a query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY amount DESC group by userid
```

I'm getting this:

```
ID | User | Amount
1  | 1    | 50
2  | 1    | 80
```

But I was expecting:

```
ID | User | Amount
9  | 2    | 300
8  | 1    | 150
```

What is wrong with my sql?

Comment: What happens when  User 2 has has two same highest amounts?? eg `300,300`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When grouping you have to use aggregate functions like `max()` for all columns that are not grouped by

```
select t.* 
from table t
inner join 
(
   SELECT userid, max(amount) as total
   FROM TABLE 
   group by userid
) x on x.userid = t.userid and x.total = t.amount
ORDER BY t.amount DESC
```

Comment: Why do you have sum there? I want to the highest entry for each user in the table?

Comment: Do you want the highest ID or just the ID of the highest amount?

Comment: i want the entire row, as is, of each user with their respective highest amounts?

Comment: Then `MAX(amount)` should be used. Put this query of juergen inside a subwuery and join it to the original table.

Comment: @juergend . . . Your statement "When grouping you have to use aggregate functions like max() for all columns that are not grouped by" is not true in MySQL.  Although I think it is a good idea, it is simply not correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You are right. I just don't think that this "Feature" is worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.Check [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aefc9/4)
Using `FIND_IN_SET` clause

```
SELECT
  ua.*
FROM user_amount ua
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ua.amount,(SELECT
                               MAX(ua1.amount)
                             FROM user_amount ua1
                             WHERE ua1.user = ua.user)) > 0
ORDER BY amount desc;
```

Using `IN` clause

```
SELECT
  ua.*
FROM user_amount ua
WHERE ua.amount IN (SELECT
                               MAX(ua1.amount)
                             FROM user_amount ua1
                             WHERE ua1.user = ua.user)
ORDER BY amount desc
```